# How to Join 2 tables into a DataGridView with checkboxes and save the state of the DGV back to the database

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have two tables. I want to use MasterList as a lookup table for the FoundFiles table to match each Filename with its Title. Foundfiles is a subset therefore of the MasterList:

```
Table "MasterList" 
  Filename 
  Title
 Table "FoundFiles"
  Filename
```

I can do a JOIN on my datatables and load them into a dataset or datatable and fill the DataGridView, but I don't understand how to then save the DataGridView, along with the checkbox state of each row, back to the database. Here is the code so far:

```
Dim con As New SqlCeConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\data.sdf")
Dim daMasterList As SqlCeDataAdapter
Dim adapt As SqlCeDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet 

Sub table_load()
  ds = New DataSet
  adapt = New SqlCeDataAdapter(("SELECT FoundFiles.Filename, MasterList.Title"                                         & _" FROM FoundFiles" & _
                                    " INNER JOIN MasterList" & _
                                    " ON FoundFiles.Filename = Masterlist.Filename"), con)
  adapt.Fill(ds, "FoundFiles")
  ' load the table into a DataGridView control
  dgvFileList.DataSource = ds.Tables("FoundFiles") 'existing files with titles from the master list
End Sub
```

If I understand things correctly, adapt.Fill(ds, "FoundFiles") has filled my in-memory dataset with the in-memory version of "FoundFiles", which is not the same as my database table with the same name (since that obviously only has one column and now I have two, the Filename AND the title). Am I correct so far? And calling .Fill automatically added the column "Filename" to the in-memory FoundFiles table?

Then I load that into a DataGridView (dgvFileList) and check several boxes. If the user does not finish checking all the boxes, I need to save the state so they can continue. I imagine I can create another table in the database with filename, description and a boolean for checked or not? Or maybe change my schema and have the FoundFiles table have Title and CheckState added to it? In any case, how do I save all the datagrid rows and their checked state to the database and load it back into the DataGridView control when the user wants to finish checking things off? When everything is checked, I will look for each row that is checked and delete the physical file matching that name that is stored in a folder. If it is easier for you, feel free to write anything in C# and I can convert it.

Comment: You can look into dataadapter update https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters

Comment: One thing to consider if you want to be able to partially process, save and then reload this data is that you'll have to load from different places in each case.  It might be a better option to start by copying all the data from `MasterList` to `FoundFiles` and then load the data from `FoundFiles` every time.